# How can I prettify json output for ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, activeadmin

I have a model with json field and I want to prettify the output for this field. How can I do it?

```
show do
  attributes_table do
    row :source_json do |model|
      model.source_json
    end
  end
end
```

Current field looks like this:

```
  {"date"=>"2018-12-17", "value"=>"sample"}
```

I want something like this:

```
  {
     "date"=>"2018-12-17",
     "value"=>"sample"
  }
```

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/915).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would go with something like this:

```
show do
  attributes_table do
    row :source_json do |model|
      JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(model.source_json))
    end
  end
end
```

You might not need the `JSON.parse` call if you have an option to get `source` as a Ruby hash instead of a JSON string.

You might want to wrap the output into a `<pre>` HTML tag – like Evan Ross suggested – to improve readability:

```
show do
  attributes_table do
    row :source_json do |model|
      tag.pre JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(model.source_json))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine inside `pre` tag: `pre JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(model.source_json))`

Comment: @EvanRoss: How do you achieve the `pre` tag?